Из-за чего выскакивает ошибка в консоли ReferenceError: document is not defined в vs code?


let bigAndRed = document.querySelector('#big-red-button');

console.log(bigAndRed.getAttribute('lang'));
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="big-red-button" onclick="alert('Бум!');" disabled>
    Кнопка самоуничтожения
  </button>
</body>
<script type="application/json" id="hydration"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>




в какой консоли ошибка? Как и что ты запускаешь?
